# lightbox effect/control for C# with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, lightbox, thickbox, imagebutton

Update:OK about ThickBox, I found the version that supports button but I get a message saying "Operation could not be completed" when I try to use the controls and add them in design mode. Not sure what else to do :( 
Any idea why I get this message?

---

I already found the Ajax Control Toolkit, but I can't install it for some reason (with Visual Studio 2008).
I also found [ThickBox](http://www.dotnet6.com/files/folders/controls/entry1107.aspx) but I couldn't figure out how to trigger a lightbox effect pop up window by clicking on a C# Imagebutton control. It needs to trigger an ASP .NET page.

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend NOT to use the AjaxControlToolKit. It's a large chunk of code for the client to download. Try to have a look at jQuery and plugins instead (eg. jqModal)

Comment: Any help on how I initiate it by clicking on an Imagebutton control? I can only see how to trigger it in Javascript or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Control Toolkit is already built into Visual Studio 2008 / Framework 3.5, the toolkit is for Studio 2005 users.

Looking at the thickbox, but that was originally released for Framework 2.0 w\ Toolkit, although the AJAX stuff is built-in, there are some compatibility issues occasionally.

[EDIT]Actually I see they have AJAX toolkit downloads explicitly for Studio 2008/.NET 3.5, Also..have you looked at the example "Test2" site that comes with the control package?? You have to make the Images to be clicked be dotnet6:ThickBoxImage 's, check out the sample, it worked fine in Visual Studio 2008 after the solution conversion was finished. And yes, jQuery and it's friends are worth looking into.

Comment: "Ajax Control Toolkit is already built into Visual Studio 2008 / Framework 3.5," - But where are all the extenders? Such as Modal Extender etc?

Comment: You are correct, I mis-typed originally, I was Editing post probably at the same time you were commenting

Comment: OK about ThickBox, I found the version that supports button but I get a message saying "Operation could not be completed" when I try to use the controls and add them in design mode. Not sure what else to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin for jQuery?

It's quite easy to use.

Comment: Is it possible to combine it in C#? Make it pop up by clicking on an Imagebutton?

Comment: Yes, just make the OnClientClick trigger the method. It's 100% javascript.

Answer (score 0):

We're using jqmodal on our project and it's great

re: crashing toolbox, could this be your issue? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vs2008sp1beta/thread/60a4b642-9495-43ec-bf3b-88526b601c99/

A solution that worked for me is found here:
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VisualStudio/microsoft.public.vsnet.ide/2008-03/msg00083.html